# How to center align the text in a text entry box in PyGTK?

Tags: pygtk, text-alignment

I created a 1-line box for text entry in PyGTK:

```
entry = gtk.Entry(max=0)
entry.set_has_frame(True)
entry.set_size_request(20, 30)
entry.connect("activate", self.enter_callback, entry)
entry.show()
```

I need to center the text horizontally. I tried many options, such as `set_justify`, `set_alignment`, etc., but none seem to work with `Entry()`.

How can I center the the text, so that when the user types there, whatever text they write is always displayed centered?

Comment: I think ***vertical*** centering in a text widget is done with `set_alignment(yalign=0.5)` in some language bindings. Does `entry.set_alignment(xalign = 0.5)` work?

Comment: Yes, that solves it!

Comment: Was it Ren or Stimpy that used to say: "happy happy happy joy joy joy!!".  I will answer and maybe you can accept :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some of the GTK language bindings vertical centering inside a text widget is set with `set_alignment(yalign=0.5)` where the number represents a proportion of white space "reserved" above the text with the remaining proportion below (I may have above and below reversed here). So `set_alignment(yalign=0.25)` would put the text 1/4 of the way below the top of the widget and `0.5` is "half way" (which is more or less equivalent to "center").

In your case, `entry.set_alignment(xalign = 0.5)` would center the text at the halfway point of the widget and align it so that the proportion on each side of the text is "`0.5`" (or half) of the remaining  white space. It's not that well documented or as easy as something like `"center"` but it gives a bit more fine grained control over the placement of the text.